# Jinja convert string to integer

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to convert a string that has been parsed using a regex into a number so I can multiply it, using Jinja2. This file is a template to be used within an ansible script.

I have a series of `items` which all take the form of `<word><number>` such as `aaa01`, `aaa141`, `bbb05`.

The idea was to parse the word and number(ignoring leading zeros) and use them later in the template.

I wanted to manipulate the number by multiplication and use it. Below is what I have done so far
```

```
{% macro get_host_number() -%}
{{ item | regex_replace('^\D*[0]?(\d*)$', '\\1') }}
{%- endmacro %}

{% macro get_host_name() -%}
{{ item | regex_replace('^(\D*)\d*$', '\\1') }}
{%- endmacro %}

{% macro get_host_range(name, number) -%}
{% if name=='aaa' %}
{{ ((number*5)+100) | int | abs }}
{% elif name=='bbb' %}
{{ ((number*5)+200) | int | abs }}
{% else %}
{{ ((number*5)+300) | int | abs }}
{% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}

{% set number = get_host_number() %}
{% set name = get_host_name() %}
{% set value = get_host_range(name, number) %}

Name: {{ name }}
Number: {{ number }}
Type: {{ value }}
```

With the above template I am getting an error `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found` which i think is telling me it cannot convert the string to integer, however i do not understand why. I have seen examples doing this and working.

Comment: That error message means you are passing an integer where it expected a string.  On which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to cast string to int after regex'ing number:

```
{% set number = get_host_number() | int %}
```

And then there is no need in `| int` inside `get_host_range` macro.